# Custom Data Source Control to use in SharePoint Designer

Tags: data-view-web-part, wss

I want to create a Custom Data Source control which can be used to bind any data bindable control in SharePoint e.g. DVWP etc. No, I am not looking for custom navigation source :)
What I have done so far is to

1. Inherit from DataSourceControl, implement ExecuteScalar and return IEnumerable
2. GACed it, register to SharePoint Page.
3. Connected a DVWP from Code view as my data source control was not available in SharePoint DataSources pane.
4. Worked perfectly and data was displayed.
   Now, I want to pass parameters collection similar to **SelectParameters** in SPDataSource but SharePoint Designer is not displaying my ParametersCollection property even though it is declared public.

Does any body know, how to create a SharePoint DataSource control which can be displayed in DataSources Pane, can have Parameters Collection like other data source controls?

I am using WSS 3.0 (yes, I am in stone age still...)